# Problems starting graphics in 18.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, ubuntu-mate, wayland

When I boot Ubuntu 18.04, either gnome or mate, the graphics do not start reliably. I have two displays, one connected to an *Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)* , the other connected to an *NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] (rev a1)*.

When I look at the output of `dmesg` with the command:

`dmesg -e | fgrep lib | wc -l`

there are 67 occurrences that look like

`[  +0.016282] gnome-shell[10729]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f678d2a5c90 sp 00007ffc220d6518 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7f678d2a3000+c000]
[May 6 19:41] gnome-shell[12827]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7426607c90 sp 00007ffe5438a058 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7f7426605000+c000]`

In most cases, the graphics will start and run normally for the rest of the session, but in some cases, not.

The problem began when I installed 18.04.  I decided to do a fresh install, so I used dpkg to create a list of packages I was originally using, and then used apt to install all of those packages after upgrading to 18.04.  Once the system comes up, it works like a champ for the rest of the session, so I think the problem is in the software, not the hardware.  Unfortunately, I don't know what additional information would be helpful.